# Inserting smiley into the HTML

Tags: javascript, html, formatting

How do I insert a smiley in the HTML programatically? I want to know the logic as how does it exist along with text? Is it a styled ASCII character or something? thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean this one - ☺

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you mean smilies as found in various forums, you simply replace the ASCII smiley with a HTML `img` element on the server side. The output will look like this:

```
<p>This is a paragraph <img src="wink.png" alt=";)"></p>
```

Most of the time this is achieved using e.g. the PHP [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function.

Comment: I have downvoted this because I am also trytiong to do this 'programatically' (for me that means ruby on rails) so yes, really do need the unicode and not `:)`

Answer (score 16):

Insert `&#x263A` into an html document to render a smiley.

Comes out like this: ☺

It renders like this because it is a unicode character (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smiley)

Comment: You can write HTML by escaping it with `\``.  (backtick)

Answer (score 2):

Hold down shift and push the :; button, then while holding down the shift key, push 0. Congrats, you've created your first smiley.

Humor aside, there are a few smiley characters that can be found in the ASCII character set. [This page](http://chexed.com/ComputerTips/asciicodes.php) lists them. In most HTML message boards/emails, however, the software replaces typed smiley faces with emoticon images.

```
Hello world <img src="smileyface.png" alt="smiley face" />!
```

Comment: @mihsathe `echo ':)';`. ;o) @Vic Humorous, but not really an answer.

Comment: There are no smiley characters in the ASCII character set. There are some in Unicode.

Answer (score 2):

There are many UTF-8 Miscellaneous Symbols are available in HTML.
Check out Below
[image]

Comment: Source? Or can you post it as text instead of an image so it can be searched, selected, copied? Or at least add an alt text that transcribes the contents for screen reader users? It's quite large and not usable in this form

Answer (score 0):

To be short, the smiley is just an image. You can store it on your server, and insert to html at client by javascript.

You may look at [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/). They do exactly what you want, and open source: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/

Comment: @MichaelDurrant: thanks for the correction. I just think that he says about the smiley often seen in forums.

Answer (score 0):

This code can post table like above into your page

```js
window.addEventListener(
    'load',
    () => {
        var txt, tr, td, table = document.createElement('table');
        for (var i = 0; i < 65536; i++) {
            tr = document.createElement('tr');
             td = document.createElement('td');
              txt = document.createTextNode(i);
             td.appendChild(txt);
            tr.appendChild(td);
             td = document.createElement('td');
              txt = document.createTextNode('\\u' + i.toString(16));
             td.appendChild(txt);
            tr.appendChild(td);
             td = document.createElement('td');
              txt = document.createTextNode(String.fromCharCode(i));
             td.appendChild(txt);
            tr.appendChild(td);
            table.appendChild(tr);
        }
        document.body.appendChild(table);
    }
);
```

Be careful, it takes about 300ms for me :)